# React Native: Active state in AppState listener getting triggered when component mounts

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have set up a listener for AppState in React Native to know when my app switches from background to foreground so I can show a splash screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
},[])

const handleAppStateChange = newState => {

    if (newState === 'active') {
      RNBootSplash.show();
    }

  };
```

The problem is, and this only happens when I compile a release APK, for some reason it works fine in debug, the splash screen is showing each time the component mounts, while it should only trigger when the app is switched into the active state from background. Any help?

Using React Native 61.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```js
const [appState, setAppState] = React.useState(AppState.currentState)

useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange)

    setAppState(AppState.currentState)

    return AppState.removeEventListener('change')
},[])

const handleAppStateChange = newState => {
    if (appState.match(/inactive|background/) && newState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
      // Show the splash screen
      RNBootSplash.show()
    } else {
      console.log('App has gone to the background!')
      // do something in background
    }

    setAppState(newState)
}
```

Comment: I tried it but no matter what I did, appState inside the handleAppStateChange would not change from its default value. I even tried useCallback and putting appState in the dependency array but nada. Only thing that work was using useRef instead of useState.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked was using refs

```
const latestAppState = React.useRef(AppState.currentState)

const handleAppStateChange = newState => {

    if (latestAppState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && newState === 'active') {
      RNBootSplash.show();

    }
    latestAppState.current = newState
  }
```